# Scraping Data from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am able to scrape the first 10 results of the maps directly through the default link, for example:

https://www.google.com/maps/search/toronto+dentist/

However I am unable to scrape the next 10 results because when I click on the right arrow, it uses Javascript to fetch the data, and there is no URL change for me to view the source of the next 10 results.

The classic Google maps version was scrapable, however the results differ from the current Google maps.

Comment: google does not want you to do this.

Comment: Although I agree with @Dagon, it is easy to see what request is being made in the console of your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use **[pjscrape.](http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/)** Instead of simply scraping the HTML, it has a full headless WebKit engine which can run the Javascript and render the page accordingly.

The API is bloody simple, just make sure that you rate-limit it because Google is *quite* fussy about that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a third party solution like SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Each page fatches 20 results. To implement the pagination just use the `start` parameter which defines the result offset (e.g., `0` (default) is the first page of results, `20` is the 2nd page of results, `40` is the 3rd page of results, etc.)

```php
require 'path/to/google_search_results';

$query = [
  "engine" => "google_maps",
  "q" => "toronto dentist",
  "ll" => "@43.7162866,-79.4689839,12z",
  "type" => "search",
  "api_key" => "SECRET_API_KEY"
];

$search = new GoogleSearch();
$results = $search->json($query);
$local_results = $result->local_results;
```

Example output:

```json
"local_results": [
  {
    "position": 1,
    "title": "Archer Dental Rosedale",
    "data_id": "0x882b2c15997e2805:0xb33e0a75557c03da",
    "reviews_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_maps_reviews&hl=en&place_id=0x882b2c15997e2805%3A0xb33e0a75557c03da",
    "gps_coordinates": {
      "latitude": 43.6715812,
      "longitude": -79.37675469999999
    },
    "place_id_search": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data=%214m5%213m4%211s0x882b2c15997e2805%3A0xb33e0a75557c03da%218m2%213d43.6715812%214d-79.37675469999999&engine=google_maps&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&type=place",
    "rating": 4.5,
    "reviews": 180,
    "type": "Dental clinic",
    "address": "600 Sherbourne St #808, Toronto, ON M4X 1W4, Canada",
    "hours": "Opens at 8:00 AM",
    "phone": "+1 416-964-0010",
    "website": "https://www.archerdental.ca/locations/archer-dental-rosedale/",
    "thumbnail": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMqm7_r6phLhJ-QMwQL1lE1ukz7DBJ4DeyK4yzK=w161-h92-k-no"
  },
  {
    "position": 2,
    "title": "Toronto Dentist Office",
    "data_id": "0x882b2d0d9df040c7:0xc2a062472b901c76",
    "reviews_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_maps_reviews&hl=en&place_id=0x882b2d0d9df040c7%3A0xc2a062472b901c76",
    "gps_coordinates": {
      "latitude": 43.777342999999995,
      "longitude": -79.41546699999999
    },
    "place_id_search": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data=%214m5%213m4%211s0x882b2d0d9df040c7%3A0xc2a062472b901c76%218m2%213d43.777342999999995%214d-79.41546699999999&engine=google_maps&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&type=place",
    "rating": 4.6,
    "reviews": 10,
    "type": "Dentist",
    "address": "5460 Yonge St Suite 201, North York, ON M2N 6K7, Canada",
    "hours": "Opens at 9:00 AM",
    "phone": "+1 416-733-7855",
    "website": "https://torontodentistoffice.ca/",
    "thumbnail": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMrNZUWbaZ7TkWUittUPY_UoWVOBO4Mj3vwyUZ7=w138-h92-k-no"
  },
  ...
],
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*